# SQL Server procedure to populate or create tables from views - performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, cursor

I have written the below code to populate/create tables (`t_`) from all of the corresponding views (`v_`) in my database. I converted a previous script from using a cursor to improve running speed. Is there anything else I can do to make this perform better?

Any help is appreciated.

Please see my code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_populate_tables_from_views] 
    @dropTables BIT
AS
    DECLARE @viewName NVARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @formattedTableName NVARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @dropTableSql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    DECLARE @viewId int

    SET @viewId = (SELECT MIN(object_id) FROM sys.views)

    WHILE @viewId IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @viewName = (SELECT name FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = @viewId)

        PRINT 'Time: ' + CONVERT(varchar, SYSDATETIME(), 121)
        PRINT('Processing ' + @viewName)

        SET @formattedTableName = REPLACE(@viewName,'v_','t_');

        IF @dropTables = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @dropTableSql = 'IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '''+@formattedTableName+''')) DROP TABLE '+@formattedTableName
            EXEC (@dropTableSql);
        END

        IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @formattedTableName))
        BEGIN
            EXEC('TRUNCATE TABLE '+@formattedTableName)
            EXEC('INSERT INTO '+@formattedTableName +' SELECT * FROM '+ @viewName) 
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            EXEC ('SELECT * INTO '+@formattedTableName+' FROM '+@viewName);
        END

        SET @viewId = (SELECT MIN(object_id) 
                       FROM sys.views 
                       WHERE object_id > @viewId)
END
```

Comment: probably want to post this on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @scsimon will do thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Just curious, have you investigated Materialized View?

Comment: I would question why you are doing it? If its for performance of ongoing queries that use the views (by pointing them at tables instead), you might want to look into indexed views. These are materialised (i.e.saved to disk) so might give you the same benefit and more i.e. no need to do this snapshotting, and they will be constantly updated rather than a snapshot. But I don't know your reasons, this might not be appropriate.

Comment: You should move this to codereview.stachexchange.com as @scsimon stated.

Comment: @JamesCasey Hi James, the reason for the process as it is - is for Database replication. Views are being constantly updated in the subscriber DB, so we recommend to users to pull data from the subscriber tables which are only updated overnight, as opposed to the views. This is the task we would run overnight to populate the tables with any updates from the primary DB.

Comment: Why not use one of the replication models available for this?

Comment: Yes, sounds like a database snapshot would work well for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. declare @sql as nvarchar(max)=''
2. SELECT @sql = @sql + '
3. IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = [' + REPLACE(name,'v_','t_') + '])
4. BEGIN
5. TRUNCATE TABLE [' + REPLACE(name,'v_','t_') + ']
6. INSERT INTO ' + REPLACE(name,'v_','t_') + ' SELECT * FROM ' + name + '
7. END
8. ELSE
9. SELECT * INTO ' + REPLACE(name,'v_','t_') + ' FROM ' + name + char(10)
10. FROM sys.views
11. print @sql
12. exec(@sql)